# How Can i remove App Name from django Admin Panel?

Tags: python, django

Actually i want to remove app names from django admin panel how can i achieve this??
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the `verbose_name` in your `apps.py` as an empty string.

Like so, using `Post` to illustrate

In `apps.py` for `Post` pass an empty string into the  `verbose_name`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PostConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'post'
    verbose_name = ' '
```

Then in `Post` `__init.py__` add

```
default_app_config = 'post.apps.PostConfig'
```

That's one hack to it.